# Are properties set in the specified order?

Tags: python, properties, initialization

Suppose I have a class with 3 instance attributes, 'a', 'b' and 'c', which are initialized each with property setters. Now, my property 'b' assignment should use the value of the instance variable 'a'. So for 'b' to be initialized, 'a' has to be initialized beforehand.

Following the code below, does python set the instance 'a' first, then goes to instance 'b', and then finnally to 'c', or may the initialisation occur in any random order, which might destroy the possibility to sucessfully initialise the variables?

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.c = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        value = self.a
        self._b = value

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self._c

    @c.setter
    def c(self, value):
        value = self.b
        self._c = value
```

I am asking this question in a simplified version because I am having difficulties in a real case. In that case, I used logs to view the execution of the execution of the initialisation, and it appears to me that it starts by executing the last property ('c' in this case), instead of the desired first, 'a'.

Comment: You can demonstrate this trivially by putting `print` in each of the setters - yes, the setters are called in the order `__init__` suggests. Please give a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You can only demonstrate that the setters executed in that order for the specific time you tried it, which doesn't prove anything general.

Comment: i managed to find the error that was causing the problem. it was actually not in the order of the execution, but in the class inheritance i was making. The first answer which states that this can be viewed with prints is correct. Thank you

Comment: @user2357112 ^ practicality beats both purity and epistomology ;o)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: "Oh, `{1:1, 2:1, 3:1}`, `{3:1, 1:1, 2:1}`, and `{3:3, 2:2, 1:1}` always show up in `1 2 3` key order when I print them! Dicts must sort their keys." That's what you get when you assume experimental results generalize. (For anyone else reading this, no, dicts do not sort their keys.)

Comment: I am really sick of people posting "why didn't you just try it" comments on questions that cannot be resolved by experimentation. If the experiment falsifies the hypothesis, sure, post the comment. If the results are inconclusive, don't act like they're definitive.

Comment: @user2357112 `dict` does sort its keys, just not in the order you'd expect.

Comment: @user2357112 OK, that's great.

Comment: @PeterWood: No. No it does not. [Not even by hash.](http://ideone.com/a9zqNL) The logic by which dicts arrange their elements is in no way a sort, whether on pre-3.6 ordering or 3.6 insertion ordering.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is like any other method in Python; the statements in it are executed in the order given, so in your example code, `a` is set before `b`, which is set before `c`, always.

The Python language spec in general provides stronger ordering guarantees than languages like C/C++ (e.g. `a, b, c = d, e, f` guarantees that `d` is read first, then `e`, then `f`, and `a` is set first, then `b`, then `c`).

It does not matter if they are properties, plain attributes, or whatever; assignment might do funky things, but those things occur in the order the statements occur.